# Finding the $n^{th}$ term of a particular recursive sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, recurrence-relations

Just recently, I encountered this problem.

> Prove or disprove that the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence
> $$a_0=0$$
> $$a_1=1$$
> $$\vdots$$
> $$a_k=2\bigg(a_{k-1}+2^{k-1}-2^{k-2}-\bigg\lfloor \frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)-1$$
> is given by
> $$a_n=\frac{(3n+1)\cdot2^n-(-1)^n}{9}.$$

In an attempt to disprove the problem, I tried to solve for the value of $a_k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,9$. However, the result of the computations tend to show that the formula for the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence above seems to be correct. So my task now is to prove that the formula for the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence is correct. However, I do not know how to begin.

Any suggestion/answer on how to solve the problem? In general, are there any available method on how to find the $n^{th}$ term of a recursive sequence such as the one above?

Comment: Since a formula for $a_n$ is already suggested in the exercise you can prove it by induction on $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much @KaviRamaMurthy for your suggestion. I will now try to do that. But in general, how does one might arrive to the formula for the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence, if we will just start by the sequence themselves?

Comment: There are many examples where a formula for $a_n$ in terms of elementary functions of $n$ is impossible. There is no general procedure even when a formula exists. The strategy one uses in general is write down a few terms and try to guess what the formula is. If you make a guess you are still obliged to prove that the formula is correct.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much again @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oeis.org is a great resource for seeing if a given sequence is known in the literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_k=2a_{k-1}+2(2^{k-1}-2^{k-2})-2\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor-1=2a_{k-1}+2^{k-1}-1-2\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor$.

We want to prove that $a_n=\frac{(3n+1)2^n-(-1)^n}{9}$ so assume that this is true for any $n<k$ (this is the induction hypothesis). Now we will prove it is also true for $k$ which finishes our proof.

$a_k=\frac{(3k+1)2^k-(-1)^k}{9}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{(3k+1)2^k-(-1)^k}{9}=2a_{k-1}+2^{k-1}-1-2\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor=\frac{2((3(k-1)+1)2^{k-1}-(-1)^{k-1})}{9}+2^{k-1}-1-2\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor$ (we replaced $a_{k-1}$ using our induction hypothesis)

So we have $3k\times2^k+2^k-(-1)^k=2(3k\times2^{k-1}-2^k)-2(-1)^{k-1}+9\times2^{k-1}-9-18\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor$ Simplfying, we get

$2^k-(-1)^k=2^{k-1}+2^{k+2}-2^{k+1}-2(-1)^{k-1}-9-18\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $9+18\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor=2^{k-1}+2^k+(-1)^k-(-1)^{k-1}$

If $k$ is even then $18\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor=6(2^{k-2}-1)$ so we have $9+6(2^{k-2}-1)=2^{k-1}+2^k+(-1)^k-2(-1)^{k-1}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $3=3$

If $k$ is odd, $18\lfloor\frac{2^{k-2}-1}{3}\rfloor=6(2^{k-2}-2)$ so from the same analysis we get the result.

So we win! $a_n=\frac{(3n+1)2^n-(-1)^n}{9}$

Comment: Thanks @Vlad for providing a detailed answer. We both arrived at the same solution using induction as suggested by KaviRamaMurthy. As a side question, suppose that only the recursive definition of the sequence is given. I am interested in a method on how to derive the $n^{th}$ term.

Comment: also I am so delighted by the word "We Win!". Thank you so much again.

Comment: Since this is a linear recurrence, you can simply purely calculate the general term. (This is what i would have done instead of induction if the term wasn;t already given). Then analyzing k mod 2, you get the term (you want to get rid of that floor function and (-1)^n)

Comment: Thank you again @Vlad for the method. Will try to do that